# Call function of plugin in header or footer file

Tags: php, oop, wordpress

I make a plugin for Wordpress with oop. I call my function in index files with

```
$wp_dyb->status();
```

But that don't work in header or footer file. There are a mean for do this ? Maybe i forgot a thing !

Or it's impossible to call a function in header or footer ? Should i make a widget ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum at first sight I will say it's a pure PHP problem.

If you defined `$wp_dyb` in your plugin file, then the scope of this variable is limited to the file.

You can try to add

```
 global $wp_dyb;
```

in your `header.php` or `footer.php`, but I'm not sure it's OK.

An other technique that I saw in som plugins : in your plugin file, you can register a function in global namespace to access to your object :

```
class WP_Dyb {
   ...
}

$wp_dyb = new WP_Dyb();

function dyb_get_object() {
  global $wp_dyb;
  return $wp_dyb;
}
```

and then in your header and footer :

```
dyb_get_object()->status();
```